# Props not passed from controller to vue component - vue2 and inertia.js

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, inertiajs

I have plenty of views where the components are passed as such

```
public function Foo(model $model) {
    return Inertia::render('Page/DetailsPage', [
        'prop' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

and the component loads with the passed prop accessible through `this.$page.props.prop` however for some reason I am trying to pass a prop in this way and cannot get it correct

`web.php` route

```
Route::get('contact-us/{division ?}{subdivision ?}', [ContactController::class, 'contactFormWithInterest'])->name('contactFormWithInterest');
```

`ContactController.php` function

```
    public function contactFormWithInterest(csiDivision $division, csiSubdivision $subdivision){
        return Inertia::render('Contact/ContactPage', [
            'subdivision' => $subdivision,
            'division' => $division
        ]);
    }
```

and the page comes out with this object structure

```
data:
    component:ContactPage
    key:<redacted>
    page:Object
        component:"Contact/ContactPage"
        props:Object
            errors:Object (empty)
...
```

`Contact/ContactPage` vue component

```
<template>
    <!-- Root div -->
    <div>
        <!-- Header -->
        <div>
            <Header class="bg-transparent"/>
        </div>
        <!-- End Header -->
        <!-- Hero image -->
        <div class="flex">
            <img src="images/hero_images/contact-us-hero.jpg" alt="Contact Hero Image" class="h-96 w-full object-cover object-center">
        </div>
        <!-- End Hero image -->
        <!-- Main container -->
        <div class="sm:p-12 sm:flex">
            <ContactUsBox :subdivision="subdivision ? subdivision : null" :division="division ? division : null"/>
        </div>
        <!-- End Main container -->
        <!-- Footer -->
        <div class="flex flex-row h-14 mt-3">
            <Footer class="w-full bg-blue-500"/>
        </div>
        <!-- End Footer -->
    </div>
    <!-- End Root div -->
</template>

<script>
import Header from '@/Shared/Header'
import Footer from '@/Shared/Footer'
import ContactUsBox from '@/Shared/ContactUsBox'
export default {
    components: {
        Header,
        Footer,
        ContactUsBox,
    },
    props: {
        subdivision: Object,
        division: Object,
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended that you do not try to access your props from the <s>`$props`</s> `$page` helper unless you're trying to access [shared data](https://inertiajs.com/shared-data).

Instead, you define your props like you'd do in any other Vue.js app.

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ user }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      user: Object,
    }
  }
</script>
```

[More info on creating pages](https://inertiajs.com/pages).

Comment: I am not accessing through `$props`, instead I access them when passed to the page this way through `this.$page.props.<prop>` not sure if that's what you meant or if there is also a `$props` element

Comment: Yeah, sorry that's my bad. I meant `this.$page`, of course. :)

Comment: I have them declared as props on the page in the correct way and as you can see pass them an object in the `web.php` route but still nothing is populating the page's props, even attempting your recommended method, odd because the url clearly indicates that the correct object is being passed along to the route

Comment: Try dumping out the variables you are passing in your controller: `dd(['subdivision' => $subdivision, 'division' => $division ])`. Could you also update your post with what your Vue component looks like?

Comment: Added the component to the question, not sure how to use `dd()`, I tried placing it above the render function in the page's controller but that didn't do anything and I couldn't find a helpful explanation on a quick web search

Comment: If you put it above the render function and nothing happens, then you're doing something wrong. It should give you a white page and a black box with the two variables printed out. I'm not sure if you can actually put a space in your route file for optional parameters. Try removing the space.

Comment: Also I noticed that you might be passing null to your child components `<ContactUsBox :subdivision="subdivision ? subdivision : null" :division="division ? division : null"/>`. Try to just print out the props in your component. ``{{ division }} {{ subdivision }}`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234188/discussion-between-liam-otoole-and-linus-juhlin).